# iOS SDK Dimensions Tracking

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to implement custom dimensions via Google Analytics. During my debug sessions I'll get everything into the right array but in GA it didn't show up.

Can anynone help me out with it?

```
(void)initGoogleAnalyticsWithSettings:(NSDictionary *)profileDict {

    NSString *trackingCode = [profileDict valueForKeyPath:@"settings.trackingCode"];
    if (trackingCode == nil) {
        trackingCode = @"UA-xxxx-1";

    }

    NSString *organisation = [profileDict valueForKeyPath:@"settings.organisation"];
    if (organisation == nil) {
        organisation = @"Unkonwn organisation";
    }

    NSArray *unitArray = [profileDict valueForKeyPath:@"settings.unit"];
    NSString *unit = [unitArray firstObject];
    if (unit == nil) {
        unit = @"Unknown unit";
    }

    NSString *userIDString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ | %@", organisation, unit];


    GAI *gai = [GAI sharedInstance];
    gai.trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;  // report uncaught exceptions

    self.tracker = [gai trackerWithTrackingId:trackingCode];
    self.tracker.allowIDFACollection = YES;
    [self.tracker set:kGAIUserId value:userIDString];
    [self.tracker set:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1] value:userIDString];
}
```

Do I need to implement tracker send event as well? 
`[tracker send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView] set:@"premium"
forKey:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1]] build]];`

Comment: when you implemented the GA in your project

Comment: in live it take minimum 24 hours thats why I asked my friend

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought and read several times. It will take a while - thats the reason why I posted the question today.